# SQL Procedure is not executing correctly With BETWEEN Keyword

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, between

[Sample Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75eef/1)[image]I’m here trying to generate a report which related to daily attendance based on the Employee ID punching. I linked 3 tables first one is “EdailyEvents (Store all Punch records), second one is “EAllocations” (Store all employee Details including their project Nos. and Group no. Called “FCode”) the third table is EPosted (Store all worked hours after reviewed by the concern).

Process is. Once the employee marked his attendance. Records will go to his superior for review against his Group No. (FCODE). Once the superior reviewed and posted man-hours those will go to EPosted Table.

So what I’m trying to do is. Generate the List of FCodes from EAllocations Table against each project no & punch date those review not been done. Below is the query which I use. I need to generate the report based on his assignment date “EReportDate” that means report should not show as pending if the report date is > review date. My Problem is when I use this line of code “EAllocations.ERportDate<=@ToDate”
Showing me as pending to review when the employee report date greater than review date.
Ex: employee Reported & assigned on 28-11-2019 (Highlighted In Yellow In EAllocations) but in report shows his reviews are pending from 21-11-2019 to 30-11-2019 (Shows "P" as marked in Report) as I’m selection date period to generate the report. @fromDate is 21-11-2019 & @ToDate is 30-11-2019.

1st I tried with Below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_Pending] 

-- ==================================================
-- DECLARE VARIABLES
-- ==================================================

@FromDate as date,
@ToDate as date,
@Pending as Varchar(1)='P'


AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
@LFromDate as date,
@LToDate as date

SET @LFromDate=@FromDate
SET @LToDate=@ToDate


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT       
EAllocations.EFCode AS 'FCODE NO.', 
EDailyEvents.EPunchDate AS 'DATE', 
EAllocations.EProjectNo 'PROJECT NO.',
EAllocations.EAdminName 'SITE ADMIN', 
@PENDING AS 'STATUS'

FROM EAllocations

INNER JOIN
EDailyEvents ON EDailyEvents.EToken=EAllocations.EToken

WHERE 
EAllocations.EReleaseDate IS NULL
AND
EAllocations.ERportDate<=@ToDate AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT EPosted.ETokenNo FROM EPosted 
WHERE 
EDailyEvents.EToken=EPosted.ETokenNo AND EDailyEvents.EPunchDate=EPosted.EPunchDate) AND EDailyEvents.EPunchDate BETWEEN @LFromDate AND @LToDate

OR

EAllocations.EReleaseDate >=EDailyEvents.EPunchDate
AND
EAllocations.ERportDate<=@ToDate AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT EPosted.ETokenNo FROM EPosted
WHERE 
EDailyEvents.EToken=EPosted.ETokenNo  AND EDailyEvents.EPunchDate=EPosted.EPunchDate) AND EDailyEvents.EPunchDate BETWEEN @LFromDate AND @LToDate

ORDER BY EAllocations.EFCode



END
```

2nd I tried With below, But Results are same.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_Pending] 

-- ==================================================
-- DECLARE VARIABLES
-- ==================================================

@FromDate as date,
@ToDate as date,
@Pending as Varchar(1)='P'


AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
@LFromDate as date,
@LToDate as date

SET @LFromDate=@FromDate
SET @LToDate=@ToDate


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  DISTINCT 
T.[FCODE NO.],
T.[DATE],
T.[PROJECT NO.],
T.[SITE ADMIN],
T.[STATUS]


FROM

(SELECT A.EFCode AS 'FCODE NO.',B.EPunchDate AS 'DATE',A.EProjectNo 'PROJECT NO.',A.EAdminName 'SITE ADMIN',A.ERportDate, @Pending AS 'STATUS'

FROM EAllocations AS A 

INNER JOIN EDailyEvents AS B ON A.EToken=B.EToken 

WHERE (
   A.EReleaseDate IS NULL OR A.EReleaseDate >=B.EPunchDate
)
AND 
    NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT P.ETokenNo FROM EPosted AS P 
    WHERE B.EToken=P.ETokenNo 
    AND B.EPunchDate=P.EPunchDate
) 

) AS T  


WHERE T.[DATE] BETWEEN @LFromDate AND @LToDate AND T.ERportDate<=@ToDate

END
```

3rd Try End With Success Thank you for everyone who try to solve this. Answer as below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_Pending] 


-- ==================
-- DECLARE VARIABLES
-- ==================

@FromDate as date,
@ToDate as date,
@Pending as Varchar(1)='P'


    AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
@LFromDate as date,
@LToDate as date

SET @LFromDate=@FromDate
SET @LToDate=@ToDate


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  DISTINCT 
T.[FCODE NO.], 
T.[DATE],
T.[PROJECT NO.],
T.[SITE ADMIN],
T.[STATUS]


FROM

(SELECT A.EFCode AS 'FCODE NO.', 
        B.EToken,
        B.EPunchDate AS 'DATE',A.EProjectNo 'PROJECT NO.',A.EAdminName 'SITE ADMIN',A.ERportDate, @Pending AS 'STATUS'

FROM EAllocations AS A 

INNER JOIN EDailyEvents AS B ON A.EToken=B.EToken 

WHERE(
        A.EReleaseDate IS NULL 
            OR A.EReleaseDate >=B.EPunchDate
     ) 

     AND a.ERportDate<=B.EPunchDate


) AS T  

WHERE T.[DATE] BETWEEN @LFromDate AND @LToDate 

AND (NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT P.ETokenNo FROM EPosted AS P 
        WHERE P.ETokenNo = T.EToken
    AND P.EPunchDate = T.[DATE]

    ))
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific. Perhaps <sql-server>.)

Comment: @ jarlh  SQL 2008 R

Comment: It helps to include DDL so that we know the data types of the columns. Comparing a `date` to a `datetime` is a common source of problems. Using `@StartDate <= MyDateTime and MyDateTime < DateAdd( day, 1, @EndDate )` makes sure that all of the times on the end date are included.

Comment: @ HABO Comparing Columns are with  "@FromDate" , "@ToDate" & PunchDate are all in "Date" data type. others are in varchar datatype (FCODE, TOKEN, SITEADMIN, PROJECT NO. & STATUS)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've over complicated things. 
I believe this is the code you're looking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_Pending] 

-- ==================================================
-- DECLARE VARIABLES
-- ==================================================

@FromDate as date,
@ToDate as date,
@Pending as Varchar(1)='P'


AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
@LFromDate as date,
@LToDate as date

SET @LFromDate=@FromDate
SET @LToDate=@ToDate


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  EAllocations.EFCode AS 'FCODE NO.', 
        EDailyEvents.EPunchDate AS 'DATE', 
        EAllocations.EProjectNo 'PROJECT NO.',
        EAllocations.EAdminName 'SITE ADMIN', 
        @PENDING AS 'STATUS'
FROM EAllocations
INNER JOIN EDailyEvents 
    ON EDailyEvents.EToken=EAllocations.EToken
WHERE (
    EAllocations.EReleaseDate IS NULL 
    OR EAllocations.EReleaseDate >=EDailyEvents.EPunchDate
)
AND EAllocations.ERportDate<=@ToDate 
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT EPosted.ETokenNo 
    FROM EPosted 
    WHERE EDailyEvents.EToken=EPosted.ETokenNo 
    AND EDailyEvents.EPunchDate=EPosted.EPunchDate
) 
AND EDailyEvents.EPunchDate BETWEEN @LFromDate AND @LToDate
ORDER BY EAllocations.EFCode

END
```

Comment: Dear @Zohar Peled, still the same result which I'm getting from my query. any way many thanks for reply.

Comment: Well, if you edit your post with sample data (as DDL+DML) and desired results, we could test our answers before posting them...

Comment: I placed an image with sample data. Data from the Eposted are quiet difficult to put in full as rows are more. Thanks.

Comment: Images don't help. Sample data is only useful when can be copied and pasted into a test environment.

Comment: @ Zohar Peled Added a download link to sample data.in excel format. Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not going to download an excel file. This is a question about SQL, use SQL tools for it. Please edit your question with proper sample data (see instructions on the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) under "How to write a good T-SQL question:" for details) and expected results as formatted text.

Comment: Dear  @Zohar Peled, I updated the link with sample data. sorry for the trouble I created earlier as I am Little confused,as I never posted any sample data before and don't know how to do it. Many thanks for you because, thanks to you I learn something new today.

Comment: That's better - this is something we can work with. However we don't know that's the desired output, so we still can't use that to test our answers.

Comment: @ Zohar Peled, for example see the Token No. T2. I put his reported date as 2019-11-28, and his attendance reviewed for dates, 2019-11-29, 2019-11-30 and 2019-12-01, which i inserted into Eposted Table. But the result shows from 2019-11-21 as pending. which is wrong. and the correct dates should be , 2019-11-28 and 1st Dec-2019 til 10th Dec-2019

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Can you edit your question once again to include the desired results as a table? It's much easier to understand like that then when reading your previous comment.

Comment: Here I added an Image of explaining the desired results with Remarks. hope this will help you to help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Still I'm searching for the answer. please anyone can help me with this. beg your pardon for the trouble.